# Laravel: How to insert multiple data with select2 to mysql database?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to insert data into database. But i don't know how to insert multi select data into the mysql database.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDy1G.png)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="languages[]" class="select2 form-control" multiple="multiple "required>
        <option selected>English</option>
        <option VALUE="french">French</option>
        <option VALUE="german">German</option>
        <option VALUE="spanish">Spanish</option>
        <option VALUE="turkish">Turkish</option>
        <option VALUE="italian">Italian</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    User::create($request->all());
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

return error

> ErrorException
> Array to string conversion

Comment: What do you see when you do a `dump($request->all())`?

Comment: **language** is not dynamic? Then change `name="languages[]"` to `name="languages"` it will be an string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$request->languges` is an **array**, and you can't save an array into a **VARCHAR()** field.
In your name attribute `languages[]` will make an **array**, not string. While name attribute  `languages` make a **string**
If you have an array,  then you need a foreach loop in your controller. 
With **select2** you need to make an *array* while sending multiple data. 
The table *property* needs to be a string not an *array*, So let's convert **array** to **string** :

**With Server-side**

With *foreach* :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $x = NULL;
    foreach($request->languages as $key => $value) {
      $x .= $value .", ";
    }
    $data['languages'] = $x;
    User::create($data);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Or, with *Implode* :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $data['languages'] = implode(',', $request->languages);
    User::create($data);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**With Client-side, `jQuery`** :

Your title says "send selected values of select box to PHP as string". You would do that in JS by catching the submit event of the form and using `.join()` to change the value of that field.

```
$('#formid').on('submit', function(){
    $('#e1').val($('#e1').val().join(','));
});
```

Your form (not given) would need an id `<form id="formid" ...>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test this code, but here's the idea. In order to insert your data,
you need to loop and insert it.

```
foreach($request->languages as $data)
       {
           Languages::create($data);
       }
    return redirect()->back();
```